# Determine if a function is essentially nonlinear

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined with parameters. For example, $f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a,b,c$ are parameters. Suppose a function $f$ with $n$ such parameters $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$.

We define a function to be *essentially linear* in its parameters if, and only if, it can be expressed in the form

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n g_i(a_i)h_i(x),$$

where $h_i$ and $g_i$ are all functions. The task is to determine if the following functions are essentially linear.

(a) $f(x) = (ax + b)^2$

(b) $f(x) = \frac{x+1}{ax}$

(c) $f(x) = \ln(ax+b)$

My answers are no, yes, and no, in that order. For (b), the proof is simple:

$$\frac{x+1}{ax} = \frac{1}{a}\cdot \frac{x+1}{x}.$$

My question is how to prove that (a) and (c) are not (or if they are). For (a), I was thinking along the line of contradiction - expanding and equating

$$f(x) = a^2x^2 + 2abx + b^2 = g_1(a)h_1(x) + g_2(b)h_2(x).$$

I presume I would have to reach a contradiction somehow, and similar for (c). But I can't see how to continue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Assume the above, and feed in $a = 0$ to get that for every $b,x$, $b^2 = g_1(0)h_1(x) + g_2(b) h_2(x)$. Thus, for every $a,b,x$, $a^2x^2 + 2abx = h_1(x)(g_1(a) - g_1(0)$. Now the LHS depends on $b$ but the RHS doesn't, and a contradiction is obvious.

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't think of that, thank you! Along the same lines for the third part then, suppose $\ln (ax+b) = g_1(a)h_1(x) + g_2(b)h_2(x)$. With $b=0$, this yields $\ln a + \ln x = g_1(a)h_1(x) + g_2(0)h_2(x)$. Would I be right in claiming this yields $h_1(x) = 1$ and $g_1(a) = \ln a$, giving $\ln (ax+b) = \ln a + g_2(b)h_2(x)$? Then $\ln (x+b/a) = g_2(b)h_2(x)$, from which the contradiction follows.